# Putting a javascript calculation result into HTML form automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function that calculates an integer sum of some variables. It's basically

```
fscalculate() = number1 + number2 + number3 = totalScore
```

where fscalculate() adds three numbers and sets the result as the variable totalScore.

I have created a form that asks the user for his name and email,
I have used a php script to send the name and email to an email address using the POST method.

**What I would like is to create a field that is automatically populated with the integer totalScore.** If this is possible then I should be able to add a line to my php script to send this with the user name and email address,

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use the HTML5 `<output>` Tag. It's designed for capturing form calculation results.

```
<form oninput="totalScore.value = (+num1.value)+(+num2.value)+(+num3.value);">
    <input type="number" id="num1" />+
    <input type="number" id="num2" />+
    <input type="number" id="num3" />=
    <output name="totalScore" for="num1 num2 num3"></output>
</form>
```

Here's a breakdown of what's happening:

- Since the input is a string, we want to coerce it into a number using
  `+someString`
- We specify the list of input IDs of fields that go into the
  calculation. Typically, this is used so that we don't get `NaN`
  result in case one of the input fields is empty. But since we're
  coercing the input into a number, an empty string is converted to 0.
  Hence, it's not necessary, but good to have for clarity (especially
  if the calculations get more complex).
- Note that we don't include `name` attributes for the number inputs.
  This is to prevent them from getting submitted. We're only concerned about the result.

Also, here's a [list of browsers](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/elements/3-output.html) that currently support `output`.

Comment: This answer looks promising! However, my PHP code looks like this:/* 
Data Variables */
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$score = $_POST['score'];


$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $name <br>
Email: $email <br>
Score: $score <br>      If I substitute totalScore for score would this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
var totalscore = num1+num2+num3;
```

Assuming your html form element is

```
<input type="text" id="score">
```

use jquery

```
$("#score").val( "hi");
```

complete test code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#score").val( "hi");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="score">
</bodY>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="total" value="" disabled />
<script>
    var totalScore = num1+num2+num3;
    document.getElementById("total").value = totalScore;
</script>
```

Good Luck!